# Can the elements that created by javascript be modified with the stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

the first 2 rows are made in the html. the third one is made with js. and the styles in the stylesheet isn't applied to the third one.
**
I want to know if there are any way to do this without styling it in js.**

```js
const record = document.createElement('div')
recordList.append(record)
const name = document.createElement('span')
name.textContent = elements[0].children[0].value
record.append(name)
```

```css
.sec1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
h1{
    margin-block: 10px;
}
.table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    // background: $orange-web;
    position: relative;
}
.back{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    position: absolute;
}
.back>div:nth-child(1){
    grid-column: span 2;
}
.back>div:not(:last-child){
    border-right: 2px dashed $gray ;
}
.records{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.records>div{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid $gray;
    margin-block: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sec1">
      <h1>Data Sheet</h1>

      <div class="table">
          <div class="back">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="records">
              <div class="record">
                  <span class="name">name</span>
              </div>
              <div class="record">
                  <span class="name">name</span>
              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the preview of my work:
[image: preview]

Comment: What's `recordList`? We need a [mcve]

Comment: The basic answer to your question is "yes" — the CSS rules apply to the entire DOM no matter where it comes from. But you have not described what **exactly** your problem is: what CSS rule appears to not work? What debugging have you done with your browser's DOM inspector?

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet we can run right here in the browser, but it has an error that `recordList` is not defined.  Please fix this.  But yes, CSS rules apply to any element as long as they match the rule, it doesn't matter where they came from.  If the CSS rule needs a class or an ID, you will have to add that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class name to the elements you dynamically created (and inserted into the DOM) with JavaScript.

```js
const record = document.createElement('div')
record.classList.add('record') // Add the 'record' class name to the DIV
recordList.append(record)
const name = document.createElement('span')
name.classList.add('name') // Add the 'name' class name to the SPAN
name.textContent = elements[0].children[0].value // Do not do this...
record.append(name)
```

Based on your provided HTML:

```html
<div class="record">
  <span class="name">name</span>
</div>
```